# Dart language: build a clock (with date and time)

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I would like to know how can I build a clock (date and current time) using Dart. I'll be binding the resulting observable string (so it refreshes automatically) to an HTML Polymer element.

I thought about using a timer to refresh the string using DateTime.now(), but this seems to be a workaround, not the best solution.

I just need to know how to code the dart file, since the HTML and Polymer elements are already configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at this example
https://github.com/bwu-dart/polymer_ui_elements/blob/master/example/polymer_ui_clock.html
https://github.com/bwu-dart/polymer_ui_elements/blob/master/lib/polymer_ui_clock/polymer_ui_clock.dart
It needs a little tweaking to work with the current Polymer version.

```dart
var oneSecond = new Duration(seconds: 1);
_timer = new Timer.periodic(oneSecond, updateTime);
```

`updateTime` is a method called every second.

Comment: Günter, I had to change enteredView() and leftView() deprecated methods with attached() and detached(). It worked, but the clock seems a little delayed. Any chance of fixing this? Can this (initially small) difference get bigger with time?

Comment: We don't maintain this package anymore. It was replaced by core-elements and paper-elements, even though they don't contain the clock (as far as I know). How big is the difference? The time is updated every second and then it newly reads the current time from the system clock (`time = new DateTime.now();`). This `Timer.periodic` may not fire exactly when the second of the system clock changes, so the deviation might go up to one second but not more.

Comment: You can make the Duration smaller (for example 50ms) but update the clock only when the second actually changed. this way you could reduce the deviation. It depends what you want to use the clock for. Currently its optimized for minimal resource usage.

Comment: You could also check the milliseconds and try to reinitialize the `Timer.periodic` when it deviates to much from the exact seconds change.

Comment: Actually I don't need it do be that precise. I was just worried about the difference getting bigger (but it doesn't). Thanks a lot, Günter!